# cant start hive metastore server

Tags: hadoop, hive

Im starting hive metastore server with this command below:

```
hive --service metastore &
```

But its not working, Im getting this errors below. But its strange this already worked and not I dont understand why stop working... The only thing I did was with spark using scala execute some queries over hive and create some tables.

This errors appear:

```
Caused by: MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)


16/04/04 23:32:39 [main]: INFO hive.metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
16/04/04 23:32:40 [main]: INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://localhost:9084
16/04/04 23:32:40 [main]: WARN hive.metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
```

And also this:

```
[hadoopadmin@hadoopSingleNode ~]$ hive --service metastore &
[1] 3773
[hadoopadmin@hadoopSingleNode ~]$ SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Starting Hive Metastore Server
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Exception thrown obtaining schema column information from datastore
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:451)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:732)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:752)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.addRole(ObjectStore.java:3228)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.addRole(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultRoles_core(HiveMetaStore.java:656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultRoles(HiveMetaStore.java:648)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5984)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5909)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hive.PARTITION_KEY_VALS' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3515)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1951)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2101)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2548)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2477)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$2.forEach(DatabaseMetaData.java:2487)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.IterateBlock.doForAll(IterateBlock.java:50)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getColumns(DatabaseMetaData.java:2361)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.adapter.BaseDatastoreAdapter.getColumns(BaseDatastoreAdapter.java:1532)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.schema.RDBMSSchemaHandler.refreshTableData(RDBMSSchemaHandler.java:921)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.schema.RDBMSSchemaHandler.getRDBMSTableInfoForTable(RDBMSSchemaHandler.java:821)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.schema.RDBMSSchemaHandler.getRDBMSTableInfoForTable(RDBMSSchemaHandler.java:770)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.schema.RDBMSSchemaHandler.getSchemaData(RDBMSSchemaHandler.java:206)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getColumnInfoForTable(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2378)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.TableImpl.validateColumns(TableImpl.java:215)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.performTablesValidation(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3393)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.addClassTablesAndValidate(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3190)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.run(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2841)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.AbstractSchemaTransaction.execute(AbstractSchemaTransaction.java:122)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.addClasses(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1605)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.addClass(AbstractStoreManager.java:954)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getDatastoreClass(RDBMSStoreManager.java:679)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getPropertiesForGenerator(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2045)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.getStrategyValue(AbstractStoreManager.java:1365)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.newObjectId(ExecutionContextImpl.java:3827)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.setIdentity(JDOStateManager.java:2571)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.initialiseForPersistentNew(JDOStateManager.java:513)
    at org.datanucleus.state.ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.newForPersistentNew(ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.java:232)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.newObjectProviderForPersistentNew(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1414)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectInternal(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2218)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectWork(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2065)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1913)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextThreadedImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextThreadedImpl.java:217)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:727)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:752)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.addRole(ObjectStore.java:3228)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.addRole(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultRoles_core(HiveMetaStore.java:656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultRoles(HiveMetaStore.java:648)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5984)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5909)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Exception in thread "main" javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Exception thrown obtaining schema column information from datastore
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:451)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:732)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:752)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.addRole(ObjectStore.java:3228)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.addRole(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultRoles_core(HiveMetaStore.java:656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultRoles(HiveMetaStore.java:648)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5984)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5909)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hive.PARTITION_KEY_VALS' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3515)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1951)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2101)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2548)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2477)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$2.forEach(DatabaseMetaData.java:2487)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.IterateBlock.doForAll(IterateBlock.java:50)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getColumns(DatabaseMetaData.java:2361)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.adapter.BaseDatastoreAdapter.getColumns(BaseDatastoreAdapter.java:1532)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.schema.RDBMSSchemaHandler.refreshTableData(RDBMSSchemaHandler.java:921)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.schema.RDBMSSchemaHandler.getRDBMSTableInfoForTable(RDBMSSchemaHandler.java:821)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.schema.RDBMSSchemaHandler.getRDBMSTableInfoForTable(RDBMSSchemaHandler.java:770)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.schema.RDBMSSchemaHandler.getSchemaData(RDBMSSchemaHandler.java:206)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getColumnInfoForTable(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2378)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.TableImpl.validateColumns(TableImpl.java:215)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.performTablesValidation(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3393)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.addClassTablesAndValidate(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3190)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.run(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2841)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.AbstractSchemaTransaction.execute(AbstractSchemaTransaction.java:122)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.addClasses(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1605)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.addClass(AbstractStoreManager.java:954)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getDatastoreClass(RDBMSStoreManager.java:679)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getPropertiesForGenerator(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2045)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.getStrategyValue(AbstractStoreManager.java:1365)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.newObjectId(ExecutionContextImpl.java:3827)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.setIdentity(JDOStateManager.java:2571)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.initialiseForPersistentNew(JDOStateManager.java:513)
    at org.datanucleus.state.ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.newForPersistentNew(ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.java:232)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.newObjectProviderForPersistentNew(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1414)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectInternal(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2218)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectWork(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2065)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1913)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextThreadedImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextThreadedImpl.java:217)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:727)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:752)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.addRole(ObjectStore.java:3228)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.addRole(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultRoles_core(HiveMetaStore.java:656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultRoles(HiveMetaStore.java:648)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5984)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5909)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136
```

I drop the mysql hive database and create again. And now when I try to start hive metastore with:

```
hive --service metastore &
```

Im getting this:

```
[hadoopadmin@hadoopSingleNode ~]$ hive --service metastore &
[1] 4102
[hadoopadmin@hadoopSingleNode ~]$ SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Starting Hive Metastore Server
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9084.
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:109)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:91)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TServerSocketKeepAlive.<init>(TServerSocketKeepAlive.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5968)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5909)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9084.
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:109)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:91)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TServerSocketKeepAlive.<init>(TServerSocketKeepAlive.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5968)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5909)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Comment: `MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hive.PARTITION_KEY_VALS' doesn't exist`... Mean anything to you? Seems like your MySQL table got messed up

Comment: When I enter in mysql prompt the table appears, but if I select (*) from that table I get this:ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'hive.PARTITION_KEY_VALS' doesn't exist. But I don't understand why I just did some queries from spark and create some views. Do you know if there is some way to fix this or its better try uninstall mysql and install again to see if fixes the issue?

Comment: Somehow you setup hive metastore with MySQL, so if I think the correct approach would be to set that back up again, yes.

Comment: I am trying to configure mysql with hive from a very very long time, Everytime I encounter errors I don't understand where I am going wrong ..... as you can see in this link https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bb86629116891e5b2d8c30b95aca9aee

hive-site.xml configuration can be seen here in the link https://gist.github.com/anonymous/44f1c9fc214136a113067cf3b4b72794

Here is file-structure 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e02b3631da940dfae880252ca72107de

Answer (score 0):

Go to lib folder of hive and delete jar containing log4j-SLF4J .
same file also exists in hadoop folder which creates this issue.